# Convention of faces in OpenGL cubemapping

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry, glsl

What is the convention OpenGL follows for cubemaps?

I followed this convention (found on a  website) and used the correspondent GLenum to specify the 6 faces `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X_EXT` but I always get wrong Y, so I have to invert Positive Y with Negative Y face. Why?

```
          ________
         |        |
         | pos y  |
         |        |
  _______|________|_________________
 |       |        |        |        |
 | neg x | pos z  |  pos x |  neg z |
 |       |        |        |        |
 |_______|________|________|________|
         |        |
         |        |
         | neg y  |
         |________|
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> but I always get wrong Y, so I have to invert Positive Y with Negative Y face. Why?

Ah, yes, this is one of the most odd things about Cube Maps. Rest assured, you're not the only one to fall for it. You see:

Cube Maps have been specified to follow the RenderMan specification (for whatever reason), and RenderMan assumes the images' origin being in the upper left, contrary to the usual OpenGL behaviour of having the image origin in the lower left. That's why things get swapped in the Y direction. It totally breaks with the usual OpenGL semantics and doesn't make sense at all. But now we're stuck with it.

*Take note that upper left, vs. lower left are defined in the context of identity transformation from model space to NDC space*

Comment: Ok, so it's not my fault! This is only a weird behaviour of OpenGL! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Here is a convenient diagram showing how the axes work in OpenGL cubemaps:

[image]

Comment: This image clarifies everything now! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't -z in OpenGL normally point forward instead of +z? Is this different for cubemaps? Also, if the bottom left of the Positive X texture is the bottom, furthest, right hand corner of the cube, isn't -Y pointing in the wrong direction compared to your axes?

Comment: "*Doesn't -z in OpenGL normally point forward instead of +z?*" Not in cubemaps. The spec is quite clear on this. "*if the bottom left of the Positive X texture is the bottom, furthest, right hand corner of the cube*" It isn't. The bottom left of the +X face maps to the *top*, right, far corner of the cube. Remember: OpenGL textures tend to be upside-down, due to the way that GL uses a bottom-left coordinate system for its faces.

Comment: Does the above image show cube map faces from inside (cube map center) or outside ?

Comment: @Irbis: Cubemaps compute the texel from a directional texture coordinate as if the direction were inside of the cube. So the faces represent the inside of the cube, as does the above diagram.

Comment: When I'm sampling in the shader, do I have to also take into account that the Z is flipped? i.e if I have a world-space direction, should I invert the Z of this direction to sample the cubemap correctly? I have made a small experiment and it looks like, yes, the Z must be inverted. But I'm not completely sure, maybe I have a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: A) @Irbis and Nicol Bolas, sorry for necroposting but I'm glad you mentioned this. I realise that there are at least 3 things to take into account: 1) The cubemap uses a left-handed instead of right-handed coordinate system. 2) The cubemap textures convention is that "down" in texture space is the positive, not negative direction, and 3) If you want to use the cubemap as a skybox, then you are looking at its faces from *inside* the cube, but if you want to use it to texture an object, e.g. an approximate sphere (which is one way to avoid problems with seams, when using an equirectangular...

Comment: B) ...aka panoramic projection - i.e. convert it to the 6 cubemap projections first, e.g. using this: https://jaxry.github.io/panorama-to-cubemap/) then you are looking at the faces from *outside* the cube.