# Do not understand captureViews in Diffuse-irradiance tutorial in learnopengl.com

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am learning IBL in https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Diffuse-irradiance.

The tutorial convert a equirectangular to a cubemap by creating 6 views.

And the views are the following code:

```
glm::mat4 captureViews[] = 
{
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f)),
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f)),
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f)),
   glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f))
};
```

I don't understand the third parameter of `glm::lookAt`.

`glm::lookAt`'s third parameter is the `up` vector. I think the `captureViews` should be:

```
// zero is    [0, 0, 0]
// right is   [1, 0, 0]
// left is    [-1, 0, 0]
// up is      [0, 1, 0]
// down is    [0, -1, 0]
// back is    [0, 0, 1]
// forward is [0, 0, -1]
glm::mat4 captureViews[] = 
{
   glm::lookAt(zero, right, up),
   glm::lookAt(zero, left, up),
   glm::lookAt(zero, up, back),
   glm::lookAt(zero, down, forward),
   glm::lookAt(zero, back, up),
   glm::lookAt(zero, forward, up)
};
```

But I totally wrong. I don't understand the magic in the tutorial's `up` vector.

Can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: The relevant part of the specification is [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification, 8.13 Cube Map Texture Selection, page 253](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Can you explain in more detail ?

Comment: Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690553/2327517](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690553/2327517)

Comment: @derhass This is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a cubemap texture is used, then a 3 dimensional direction vector has to be transformed, to 2 dimensional texture coordinate relative to one side of the map.

The relevant part of the specification for this transformtion is [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification, 8.13 Cube Map Texture Selection](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=275&zoom=100,0,614), page 253:

> When a cube map texture is sampled, the `(s t r)` texture coordinates are treated
>   as a direction vector `(rx ry rz)` emanating from the center of a cube. The `q` coordinate is ignored. At texture application time, the interpolated per-fragment direction vector selects one of the cube map face’s two-dimensional images based on the largest magnitude coordinate direction (the major axis direction). If two or more coordinates have the identical magnitude, the implementation may define the rule to disambiguate this situation. The rule must be deterministic and depend only on `(rx ry rz)`. The target column in table 8.19 explains how the major axis direction maps to the two-dimensional image of a particular cube map target.
>   Using the `sc`, `tc`, and `ma` determined by the major axis direction as specified in table 8.19, an updated `(s t)`
>   is calculated as follows:
>
> ```
> s = 1/2 * (s_c / |m_a| + 1)
> t = 1/2 * (t_c / |m_a| + 1)
>
>
> Major Axis Direction|        Target             |sc |tc |ma |
> --------------------+---------------------------+---+---+---+
>        +rx          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X|−rz|−ry| rx|
>        −rx          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X| rz|−ry| rx|
>        +ry          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y| rx| rz| ry|
>        −ry          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y| rx|−rz| ry|
>        +rz          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z| rx|−ry| rz|
>        −rz          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z|−rx|−ry| rz|
> --------------------+---------------------------+---+---+---+
> ```

`sc` cooresponds the u coordiante and `tc` to the `v` cooridnate. So `tc` has to be in the direction of the view space up vector

---

Look at the first row of the table:

> ```
> +rx | TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X | −rz | −ry | rx
> ```

This means, for the X+ side (right side) of the cube map, the directions which correspond to the tangent and binormal are

```
sc = (0, 0, -1)
tc = (0, -1, 0)
```

This perfectly matches the 1st row of the table `glm::mat4 captureViews[]`:

> ```
> glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f))
> ```

because the major direction is given by the line of sight, which is the directon form the eye position to the target (`los = target - eye`) and so (1, 0, 0).
The up vector (or  `ts`) is (0, -1, 0).
`sc` is given by the cross product of the line of sight and the up vector (0, 0, -1).